# I'm trying to make a list of things to show on exact days of the week

Tags: python, pysimplegui

So I'm trying to make it to show a list of things in PySimpleGUI and it doesn't work because of this problem "Expected type 'list[list[Element]]', got 'list[list[() -> None]]' instead" the error is about "sg.Column(asdf)".

Also how do I put text in the next line like clicking enter in the notepad?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import requests
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
dzien = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
data = datetime.date.today()

week_days=["Poniedziełek", "Wtorek", "Środa", "Czwartek", "Piątek", "Sobota", "Niedziela"]

pon = ["Historia", "Matematyka", "Niemiecki", "Chemia", "Fizyka"]
wt = ["Angelski", "Informatyka/PP", "Biologia", "Matematyka"]
sr = ["Angileski", "Fizyka", "Matematyka", "Polski", "Wychowawcza"]
czw = ["Nic/WOS", "WF", "Religia", "Geografia"]
pt = ["Matematyka", "Polski", "Fizyka"]



def lekcje():
    if dzien == 0:
        sg.Text(pon)
    elif dzien == 1:
        sg.Text(wt)
    elif dzien == 2:
        sg.Text(sr)
    elif dzien == 3:
        sg.Text(czw)
    elif dzien == 4:
        sg.Text(pt)

asdf = [[
    lekcje
]]



layout =  [[
    sg.Column(asdf),
]]

window = sg.Window("Zegar", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

In following statements, it show the element used in `asdf` is a function, not the result of function, `sg.Text()`. So it should be `[[lekcje()]]`

```py
asdf = [[lekcje]]
layout =  [[sg.Column(asdf),]]
```

Another issue found in function `lekcje`, weekday may be fron 0 to 6, it will return `None` when weekday is 5 or 6. Then the layout `asdf` will be `[[None]]`. So it should return something for case 5 or 6.

If you want all items shown in `sg.Text`, here's example

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import requests
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
dzien   = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
data    = datetime.date.today()

week_days = ["Poniedziełek", "Wtorek", "Środa", "Czwartek", "Piątek", "Sobota", "Niedziela"]

pon = ["Historia", "Matematyka", "Niemiecki", "Chemia", "Fizyka"]
wt  = ["Angelski", "Informatyka/PP", "Biologia", "Matematyka"]
sr  = ["Angileski", "Fizyka", "Matematyka", "Polski", "Wychowawcza"]
czw = ["Nic/WOS", "WF", "Religia", "Geografia"]
pt  = ["Matematyka", "Polski", "Fizyka"]

week_subject = {0:pon, 1:wt, 2:sr, 3:czw, 4:pt}
width   = max(map(lambda x:max(map(len, x)), week_subject.values()))
height  = max(map(len, week_subject.values()))

def lekcje(dzien, size):
    text = '\n'.join(week_subject[dzien]) if dzien < 5 else ''
    return sg.Text(text, size=size)

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
sg.set_options(font=('Couier New', 16))

asdf = [[lekcje(dzien, (width, height))]]
layout =  [[sg.Column(asdf)]]
window = sg.Window("Zegar", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```